# Finding sum of the elements Subset of length k

Tags: arrays

Suppose we have a set  `S=(1,2,3)`
let k be the length of the subset,then we are
required to find the sum of elements of subset of S of length k

Eg (1,2,3)

```
if k=2
s1(1,2) ans sum=3
s2(1,3) ans sum=4
s3(2,3) and sum=5
```

We know there will nCk way of choosing those numbers but what is the appraoch of choosing in those subsets in optimal way???

Comment: There is no optimal way.  This is a simply SUM algorithm.

Comment: As this is a theoretical question more than a coding question, this question might be better suited here: http://cs.stackexchange.com/.